# How can i deal a hand in python

Tags: python-3.x

im trying to deal a hand in python with random.shuffle and its keeps giving me an error, can some one help me figure out whats wrong with it.

```
# [import statements]
import q1fun
# [constants]

# [rest of program code]
number = input("howmany cards to you want dealt?")
a = q1fun.deal(number)
print (a)

# [import statements]
import random
# [constants]

def deal(x):


    y = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13]
    a = random.shuffle(y(x))


    return(a)
```

howmany cards to you want dealt?5
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Eddie\workspace\cp104\durb8250_a16\src\q1.py", line 18, in 
    a = q1fun.deal(number)
  File "C:\Users\Eddie\workspace\cp104\durb8250_a16\src\q1fun.py", line 29, in deal
    a = random.shuffle(y(x))
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable

Comment: are you trying to append **x** to **y** ? y is not a function, and thus cannot be called with y(argument).

Comment: What is `y(x)` supposed to do?

Answer (score 1):

`random.shuffle(y)` shuffles the list `y` inplace and returns `None`. 
So

```
def deal(n):
    "Return a hand of n cards"
    y = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9,
         10, 11, 12, 13, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6,
         7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13]
    random.shuffle(y)
    return y[:n]
```

might be closer to what you want.

Or omit `random.shuffle(y)` and just use `random.sample`:

```
return random.sample(y, n)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to reference an element of a list with function call parentheses. You want to use square brackets.

```
function(x)    <-- calls the function with parameter x
list[x]        <-- gets the x-th element of the list
```

Also, your input is going to be returning a string. You'll need to convert it to an integer before using it to reference an index. I.e. `random.shuffle(y[int(x)])`

And finally, your shuffle call won't work. You want to shuffle first (which shuffles the list [*in place*](http://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.shuffle)), then get the element

```
random.shuffle(y)
a = y[int(x)]
```